# Copy directory but not recurse

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, rsync, cp

I want to copy a directory without recursing, preserving "everything", sort of like `cp -a` except that -a will do the unwanted recursing.

The reason is I am making a script to copy/backup from an unreliable source, so I copy files and directories one by one, keeping a log that is used to avoid redoing already successful copies and stay away from problematic source files when starting over after a failure.

Since `cp -a` is equivalent to `cp -dR --preserve=all`, I tried taking the -R away from that, but cp then skips directories because the recursion is off.

Comment: `rsync` can do anything what `cp` doing. Use rsync's exclude directive as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178363

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? In general you need a good tool/approach to deal with an unreliable source, not necessarily `cp`.